# Should psd files be converted to html before creating Django templates?

Tags: html, django, django-templates

To convert from a good design (PSD files) to a good looking web site, it seems an effective approach is to use a PSD to HTML service.

For a Django site (which mine is), you typically need a bunch of templates to dynamically define many parts of the web pages.

It seems to me that converting PSD to HTML is a different skill to coding up Django templates, which are closely linked to the rest of the Django application. And while there may be developers who are very skilled in both skills, the number is probably small. But there are many quality PSD to HTML services, and a reasonable number of Django contract developers.

My question: For best results, should I split the tasks, and get the PSD to HTML done first, and then pass the HTML files to the Django developer?
Or is that likely to be a waste of time & money? Should I just pass the PSD files to the Django developer and hope he/she has the necessary HTML/CSS skills?

(ps. Have looked thru Django & Django-templates + HTML. Question not found.)

Comment: For whatever it's worth, all PSD to HTML output that I've ever seen is complete garbage and impossible to work with. You'll probably want someone with CSS experience, in theory you can do it without touching any HTML files at all (in practice, probably a few minor edits). I would hope that any developer you work with has basic HTML and CSS skills, it's not witchcraft.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly - get someone to do it manually. Those automatic psd to html generators either works based on tables (create aLOT of code and alot of hard to read code) or based on divs, which means ALOT of absolutely positioned elements. Thats what my experience tells anyway. Neither of those cases really produces quality, fluid, reusable code.

You need someone who does not necessarily know django (cause backend framework is irrelevenat to psd to html/css skills), but rather someone who is (very) good with html(5) and css(3).

Also - converting PSD to HTML/CSS is not a simple task, unless your PSD design features all necessary elements. I mean all - like link in content area may be with one design, link in some other area usually has different design, do links in lists have different design compared to links in (other) content? Does your design feature all possible form elements design? Does your psd feature all necessary/possible elements in most areas? If yes, then converting your design to css/html is pretty easy task. If not, then you probably need to keep tab open and use your html wizards services any time you find out that design for element X is missing because your django form.as_ul or form.as_table prints out form in a way that your html guy did not think of.